# Restricting second date in jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

This was marked as duplicate, but i can't see that. The other post was related to restrict second date to currently selected date in the first pick, i'm not trying to do that, already have that. I'm trying to add +3days to the second calendar/date. So if i select today on the first date and the on the second date i should not be able to select dates from that date + 3 days.

I'm having issues with date-range in my datepicker. I need to have the "carrental_to_date" with minimum 3 days after the selected "carrental_from_date" but nothing seems to work.

I have tried changing the "minDate" on the "to_date" to "+3d" but it not seems to pick that up, i did find one example of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/dxbtp/494/ but i'm not able to get that working either. Not sure what i'm doing wrong here and was hoping one of you geniuses was able to point me in the right direction.

```
jQuery('#carrental_from_date' + element_id).datepicker({
                //showOn: "both",
                beforeShow: carrental_customRange,
                dateFormat: "<?php echo date_format_js(isset($theme_options['date_format']) ? $theme_options['date_format'] : ''); ?>",
                firstDay: "<?php echo (isset($theme_options['date_format_first_day']) ? (int) $theme_options['date_format_first_day'] : 0); ?>",
                dayNamesMin: ["<?php echo CarRental::t('Su') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Mo') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Tu') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Wu') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Th') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Fr') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Sa') ?>"],
                monthNames: ["<?php echo CarRental::t('January') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('February') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('March') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('April') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('May') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('June') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('July') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('August') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('September') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('October') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('November') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('December') ?>"],
                dayNames: ["<?php echo CarRental::t('Sunday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Monday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Tuesday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Wednesday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Thursday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Friday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Saturday') ?>"],
                nextText: "<?php echo CarRental::t('Next') ?>",
                prevText: "<?php echo CarRental::t('Prev') ?>",
                minDate: 0,
                onSelect: function() {
                    carrental_update_business_hours(element_id);
                }
            });

            jQuery('#carrental_to_date' + element_id).datepicker({
                //showOn: "both",
                beforeShow: carrental_customRange,
                dateFormat: "<?php echo date_format_js(isset($theme_options['date_format']) ? $theme_options['date_format'] : ''); ?>",
                firstDay: "<?php echo (isset($theme_options['date_format_first_day']) ? (int) $theme_options['date_format_first_day'] : 0); ?>",
                dayNamesMin: ["<?php echo CarRental::t('Su') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Mo') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Tu') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Wu') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Th') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Fr') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Sa') ?>"],
                monthNames: ["<?php echo CarRental::t('January') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('February') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('March') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('April') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('May') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('June') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('July') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('August') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('September') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('October') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('November') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('December') ?>"],
                dayNames: ["<?php echo CarRental::t('Sunday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Monday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Tuesday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Wednesday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Thursday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Friday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Saturday') ?>"],
                nextText: "<?php echo CarRental::t('Next') ?>",
                prevText: "<?php echo CarRental::t('Prev') ?>",
                minDate: 0,
                onSelect: function() {
                    carrental_update_business_hours(element_id);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you, tried the search and did not see this one. I will take a look.

Comment: Updated the post, this is not a duplicate of the earlier post.